# Oracle database mount with files

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, sap, database-administration

We are currently working on SAP Oracle 11g database import in different server.

Client gave us control files, DB files, redo log files.

Followed steps:

1. created new database with same name.
2. copied all control files, DB files and redo log files.
3. Modified init.ora file with clients control file name.
4. Alter database mount:

   > ```
   > ERROR at line 1:
   > ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
   > ```
   >
   > [image]
5. Create new control file using DB files use create control file command:

   ```
    CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "<DBNAME>" NORESETLOGS ARCHIVELOG
        MAXLOGFILES 20
        MAXLOGMEMBERS 5
        MAXDATAFILES 100
        MAXINSTANCES 8
        MAXLOGHISTORY 292
    LOGFILE
      GROUP 1 (
        'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\oraredo2\<DBNAME>\redo01a.log',
        'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\oraredo2\<DBNAME>\redo01b.log'
      ) SIZE 50M ,
      GROUP 2 (
        'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\oraredo2\<DBNAME>\redo02a.log',
        'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\oraredo2\<DBNAME>\redo02b.log'
      ) SIZE 50M ,
      GROUP 3 (
        'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\oraredo2\<DBNAME>\redo03a.log',
        'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\oraredo2\<DBNAME>\redo03b.log'
      ) SIZE 50M 
    -- STANDBY LOGFILE
    DATAFILE
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\system01.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\undotbs01.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\sysaux01.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\users01.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\<DBFILENAME>.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\<DBFILENAME>.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\<DBFILENAME>.dbf',
      'C:\app\Orcldba\oradata\<DBNAME>\<DBFILENAME>.dbf'
    CHARACTER SET KO16KSC5601
    ;
   ```

   Error:

   > ```
   > ERROR at line 1:
   > ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
   > ORA-01565: error in identifying file 'C:WappWOrcldbaWoradataWXXXXXXXX.dbf'
   > ORA-27048: skgfifi: file header information is invalid
   > OSD-04001: invalid logical block size (OS 2097152)
   > ```
   >
   > [image]

Not found any help from google.

Comment: And have you checked the alert log for more info, as the first error message advised. Also, please note that this is a Q&A site, we're all volunteers here and you do not have an SLA wit us. If you want help ASAP you should pay Oracle for a support contract.

Comment: Specify the SQL to create the controlfile.
You do not have the same size as the blocksize of the control file and the datafiles.

Comment: Checked alert log and found same error message there.

Comment: Show  the parameter  db_block_size from spfile or pfile original database and new database.

Comment: db_block_size=8192

Comment: try before run sqlplus, you need `set NLS_LANG=american_america.KO16KSC5601 ` then run `sqlplus / as sysdba` and `create controlfile`

Comment: What is version OS and 32/64 bit original server and new server? What is version oracle software on original server and new server?

Comment: Our OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit, Don't know client's configuration. Oracle 11g on both server.

Comment: thanks Dmitry dmin, I am trying this NLS_LANG=american_america.KO16KSC5601

Comment: facing same errors after setting NLS_LANG=american_america.KO16KSC5601.

Comment: I think the original platform is not Intel (Sparc). To migrate between platforms that have a different endian format, Cross Platform Transportable Tablespaces (XTTS) needs to be used instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174338/discussion-between-dmitry-demin-and-dinesh).

Comment: I have checked Cross Platform Transportable Tablespaces (XTTS) but all steps starting from source location. We don't have source system. We have only control files, data files and redo log files.

Comment: You must to know the hardware platform SPARC, POWER.
You need to know the exact release of Oracle 11.2.0.1 or 11.2.0.4 and a bit 32 or 64 bits. You can run on a new windows server RMAN Endian Conversion  and  run Cross Platform DB Migration using RMAN

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry Demin for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the difference in the hardware platform of the original database of the new database. To migrate between platforms you need access to the source server, you must run  Cross Platform DB Migration using RMAN. 
I tried doing a test migration from Oracle 10.2.0.4 Solaris 10 Sparc 64 on Oracle 10.2.0.4 Oracle Linux 32 and got similar errors.

```
SELECT A.platform_id, A.platform_name, B.endian_format 
FROM v$database A, v$transportable_platform B 
WHERE B.platform_id (+) = A.platform_id;

-bash-3.00$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Jul 5 07:57:44 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> set linesize 1000
SQL>
SELECT A.platform_id, A.platform_name, B.endian_format
FROM v$database A, v$transportable_platform B
WHERE B.platform_id (+) = A.platform_id;SQL>   2    3

PLATFORM_ID PLATFORM_NAME                                    ENDIAN_FORMAT
----------- --------------------------------------------- --------------
          2 Solaris[tm] OE (64-bit)                              Big

SQL>


[oracle10@aktp ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Jul 5 08:01:53 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>  set linesize 1000
SQL> SELECT A.platform_id, A.platform_name, B.endian_format
FROM v$database A, v$transportable_platform B
WHERE B.platform_id (+) = A.platform_id;  2    3

PLATFORM_ID PLATFORM_NAME                                   ENDIAN_FORMAT
----------- -------------------------------------------- --------------
         10 Linux IA (32-bit)                                  Little
```

Followed steps:

1) copied all control files, DB files and redo log files.

2) Modified init.ora file with clients control file name.

3) Alter database mount:

```
ORA-00202:controlfile:[/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/o1_mf_488h0hfl_.ctl]
ORA-27047: unable to read the header block of file
Additional information: 2
```

I tried to create a controlfile, and got errors.

```
Errors in file /oracle/app/oracle/admin/ST01/udump/st01_ora_695.trc:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file '/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/o1_mf_system_488h0zbs_.dbf'
ORA-27047: unable to read the header block of file
```

I tried to run Cross Platform DB Migration using RMAN, and got errors.

```
    [oracle10@aktp ST01]$ rman target /

    Recovery Manager: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Tue Jul 10 10:39:54 2018

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    connected to target database: ST01 (not mounted)

        RMAN> CONVERT DATAFILE

          '/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/o1_mf_system_488h0zbs_.dbf_',
          '/oracle/app/or2> 3> 4> acle/oradata/ST01/o1_mf_sysaux_488h1hvj_.dbf_'
           FROM PLATFORM 'Solaris[tm] OE (64-bit)'
        5> 6> ;

        Starting backup at 10.07.18
        using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
        allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
        channel ORA_DISK_1: sid=167 devtype=DISK
        channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile conversion
        input filename=/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/o1_mf_sysaux_488h1hvj_.dbf_
        RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
        RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
        RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
        RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 07/10/2018 10:41:43
        RMAN-10038: database session for channel ORA_DISK_1 terminated unexpectedly
```

If run migration on Oracle 11.2.0.3 Linux 64 bit,

```
oracle@esmd:/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01> rman target /

Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Jul 10 11:01:03 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: ST01 (not mounted)

RMAN>

RMAN>  CONVERT
2>   FROM PLATFORM 'Solaris[tm] OE (64-bit)'
3> DATAFILE
4>   '/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/system.dbf'
5> FORMAT
  '/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/system.dbf_';
6>
Starting conversion at target at 10-JUL-18

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
CONVERT
  FROM
PLATFORM 'Solaris[tm] OE (64-bit)'
DATAFILE
  '/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/sysaux.dbf'
FORMAT
  '/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/sysaux.dbf_';allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=140 device type=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile conversion
input file name=/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/system.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of conversion at target command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 07/10/2018 11:01:06
ORA-19928: CONVERT of data files with undo segments between different endian is not supported.

RMAN>
RMAN> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6> 7> ;

Starting conversion at target at 10-JUL-18
using channel ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile conversion
input file name=/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/sysaux.dbf
converted datafile=/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/ST01/sysaux.dbf_
channel ORA_DISK_1: datafile conversion complete, elapsed time: 00:01:05
Finished conversion at target at 10-JUL-18
```